# webbrowser.open() doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, python, kivy, pyjnius

webbrowser.open() works on Windows 7; Python 2.7 opens my default web browser (Chrome) on my Windows machine no problem.
 
My simple code to analyze CSV data works perfectly on both Windows and Android (4.1). `webbrowser.open() or .get()` does not work on Android with Firefox and Chrome.
 I'm plotting/drawing analyzed data on Google Map on a browser. It's such a simple thing to do yet Python doesn't even find a "runnable" browser on Android.

I'm using QPython and Kivy Launcher to run my Python code on Android.

```
     QPython Log of webbrowser.get() or webbrowser.open(); 
     "webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser."
```

Even if webbrowser.get(browser_path).open(url) worked, it's a bit of pain having to find a "runnable" browser among many possible browsers' path.

What API/module/trick do you wizards use, Pyjnius to call Android API?

```
"Mmmm, pieThong, uuugghhh..."
```

Comment: Do you want an analog of: `import android; android.Android().startActivity('android.intent.action.VIEW', url)`?

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response & tips, much appreciated! I prefer using just Python 2.7, but that may not be an option in this case.

Comment: There is a Python code importing Android to open browser:
[GitHub knappador/kivy-browser](https://github.com/knappador/kivy-browser/blob/master/src/browser/androidbrowser.py).  

But I think it's such a common operation that Python should be able to handle it (unless I'm doing something wrong!)

Comment: Are you able to test by building your own apk rather than using qpython or the kivy launcher? Python-for-android *does* register a browser for android, so this should work. I would have thought this would work with what you're already trying, but maybe not.

Comment: Failing that, knappador's method is good.

Comment: Wow!...inclement "the Kivy" himself!...I wish I had your brain!...
I didn't think of building APK to get it to work. I thought it would be a waist of time if I can't even get the code running first on Android. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Using webbrowser is not an option on Android so far. Instead you can use [Pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
from jnius import autoclass, cast

def open_url(url):
    Intent = autoclass("android.content.Intent")
    Uri = autoclass("android.net.Uri")
    PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")

    i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url))

    current_activity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
    current_activity.startActivity(i)
```

Reference: [Pyjnius documentation](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/android.html#accessing-the-activity)